# Imported excel sheet has a date column that follows two different formats (MM-DD-YYYY) and (DD-MM-YYYY) at the same time. How do I fix this?

Tags: excel, database

I have an imported excel file that has date column that shows date and time as shown below [image: here].

The weird thing is the dates follow two different formats at the same time. How do I force excel to follow either one of the two formats?

Comment: It looks like second half is text, not datetime. Is this Excel or CSV file and did you look at the actual source?

Comment: its saving as an .xls file so I assume it is not a CSV.

Comment: How do you not know whether the file you open is csv or xls/xlsx? Can you check/confirm the type of value in cells 1-32 and 33-onwards? Again, just looking at the screenshot my guess is that second half is text, not datetime. If this is the case you can use `DATEVALUE` formula to convert to proper `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

You can Do the following procedure which is easiest and best for you

Select Column A

Press CTRL+1 OR Go to Custom Formatting

go to Custom in the most last option

in the bar, copy this format

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

or if you want the time in AM/PM then copy following format

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

Press Enter, and everything will be in the same format

[image]